# Force Truncate Author List in Citation for long list of authors

Tags: natbib, elsarticle

I am writing an research article using `elsarticle`. It uses `natbib` with a custom `bst` file for citation. I could not modify it in a way so that in citation, it would truncate the authors list with `et~al.` if there are more than certain number of authors. The standard natbib with popular `bst` files like `apacite` already does this by default. The custom `bst` file is available in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ydifp8m1)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\section{Introduction}
According to \Citet{Hensley2008}
```

Where the bib file contains

```
@inproceedings{Hensley2008,
author = {Hensley, Scott and Wheeler, Kevin and Sadowy, Greg and Jones, Cathleen and Shaffer, Scott and Zebker, Howard and Miller, Tim and Heavey, Brandon and Chuang, Ernie and Chao, Roger and Vines, Ken and Nishimoto, Kouji and Prater, Jack and Carrico, Bruce and Chamberlain, Neil and Shimada, Joanne and Simard, Marc and Chapman, Bruce and Muellerschoen, Ron and Le, Charles and Michel, Thierry and Hamilton, Gary and Robison, David and Neumann, Greg and Meyer, Robert and Smith, Phil and Granger, Jim and Rosen, Paul and Flower, Dennis and Smith, Robert},
booktitle = {2008 IEEE Radar Conference},
doi = {10.1109/RADAR.2008.4720722},
isbn = {978-1-4244-1538-0},
month = {may},
pages = {1--6},
publisher = {IEEE},
title = {{The UAVSAR instrument: Description and first results}},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4720722/},
year = {2008}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question can be improved by adding a small example document (you can use the `edit` link at the bottom of the post for this). This example document should contain the class, the bibliography style declaration, a citation, and the bibliography itself. This makes it easier for the community here to reproduce the issue and suggest possible solutions.

Comment: But, if you are planning to submit to Elsevier using this bibliography style, then you are probably not allowed to make any changes to the appearance of the bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}` with `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`.